# finding the lowest values in three date columns which are related

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database which should contain data from 01/04/2016 and I need to check this, the format of the columns is the week of the year is in 1 column, year is in another and month of year is in another column I have tried to find the data using this query which I do not think is accurate:

```
  select min(week), min(month), min(year) from adgroupanalysis;
```

Can anyone suggest how I can do this please?

Comment: How does finding the minimum of these columns verify what you need? Should all the data be from 01/04/2016, or should it just contain data from 01/04/2016 for some records?

Comment: the table contains 28 million rows so without the need to review them I need to make sure I have data between these two periods of 01/04/2016 and today.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the row with the minimum date, then you can use:

```
select aga.*
from adgroupanalysis aga
order by year, week
limit 1;
```

You should store the date in a proper format.

Comment: Thanks, how would I find the maximum date using this formula?

Comment: You would add `desc` twice to get a descending sort.